# Reinforcement Learning Policy

Tags: reinforcement-learning

[image]

I really have searched thoroughly why this Sum in the circle isn't equal to 1?
The rationale is that being in a specific state s the sum of the probabilities taking all the available actions (while in state s) is 1.

So my question is: why this sum is not equal to one?

Comment: You need to give some context about the formula. What is the formula (name?), what do the symbols represent, what do you expect from it, do you have any code that causes problems? This question as of right now is plainly too vague.

Comment: @Lexpj it is the formula of state value function in reinforcement learning known as Bellman's Equation for state values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely dependent on your policy function for a valid explanation. I will use epsilon-greedy for this thread.

Epsilon-greedy is a semi-greedy algorithm that includes exploration by a parameter epsilon. In pseudocode, epsilon-greedy looks something like this:

```
def egreedy(s):
    """s is the state you are currently in"""
    theta <- random float in [0,1]
    if theta < epsilon:
        return random action (which is not the greedy action)
    return greedy action
```

To simply put it, if you have an epsilon of 0.1, there is a 0.9 proportion of picking the greedy action and 0.1/(#a-1) proportion for each other action. #a denotes the number of actions available. For example, if there are 5 actions, then the following applies:
0.9 proportion for greedy action
0.1/(5-1)=0.025 for each other action.

Then to get back to your question, this adds up to one, since all proportions combines yields 1, which is only logical since you will always pick an action, and thus all proportions should add up to 1.

Now, I used epsilon-greedy here, but another policy might yield you other values that may not be in that range. This is due to not having the proportions normalized. Something like Softmax would solve this. Softmax applies normalisation such that the proportions of a set of values will add up to 1. This formula is easy to look up and apply, so I will leave this out of this thread.

To conclude, sum_a pi(a|s) should add up to 1. If not, the values are not normalized. Use something like Softmax to solve this.

Comment: Your explanation seems rational, if I find something else relevant to the topic I will add it here. Thank you.